# Execute command to remote server via SSH after exporting variable

Tags: ssh, script, environment-variables, export

I have two machines, A and B. I need to execute a script which is located in B by SSHing there from A.

In order for the script to run I also need to export a variable. If I just SSH and export the variable and then try again to SSH and execute the script, the variable is no longer available.

Is there a way to export the variable and make it available in the same session with the script?

I was hoping for something like this (but it doesn't work):

```
ssh root@B export PATH=$PATH:/add/stuff/here && runScript.sh
```

Even if I do the following, the path isn't updated:

```
ssh root@B export PATH=$PATH:/add/stuff/here && echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're slightly wrong in passing the third argument. In the command you've provided you pass instructions as many arguments, and, additionally, you `echo` local `$PATH`. You must pass the whole command as one argument, in single quotes.

Instead of

```
ssh root@B export PATH=$PATH:/add/stuff/here && echo $PATH
```

Which is:

```
(ssh + root@B + export + PATH=...) && (echo + $PATH)
```

You should do:

```
ssh root@B 'export PATH="$PATH:/add/stuff/here" && echo $PATH'
```

Which is:

```
ssh + root@B + '(export + PATH=..) && (echo $PATH)'
```